# kotlin retrofit expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1

Tags: android, arrays, api, kotlin, retrofit

I tried to create an application, the essence of which is that by pressing a button, the author and title from my api are displayed, but it gives an error expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1, I tried everything, nothing works, what is the problem

MainActivity.kt:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    btn.setOnClickListener {
        sendNetworkRequest()
    }
}
fun sendNetworkRequest(){
    val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://newsapi.org/v2/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    val retrofit = builder.build()
    val apiInterface: ApiInterface = retrofit.create<ApiInterface>(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val call: retrofit2.Call<UrlImageModel> = apiInterface.getFile()
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<UrlImageModel>{
        override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<UrlImageModel>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("LOL",t.message.toString())
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<UrlImageModel>, response: Response<UrlImageModel>) {
            val statusResponse = response.body()!!
                        result.text = result.text.toString() + '\n' + statusResponse.status


        }
    })
}
```

ApiInterface.kt:

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("everything?q=bitcoin&from=2020-09-12&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=1d4f4f812b0b458890db5757fa0d8ce0")
fun getFile(): Call<UrlImageModel>
```

}

UrlImageModel.kt

```
class UrlImageModel {
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
var status: String? = null
@SerializedName("totalResults")
@Expose
var totalResult: String? = null
@SerializedName("articles")
@Expose
var articles = ArrayList<Articles>()
```

}

```
class Articles{
@Expose
@SerializedName("source")
var source = ArrayList<Source>()
@SerializedName("author")
@Expose
var author: String? = null
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
var title: String? = null
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
var description: String? = null
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
var url: String? = null
@SerializedName("urlToImage")
@Expose
var urlToImage: String? = null
@SerializedName("publishedAt")
@Expose
var publishedAt: String? = null
@SerializedName("content")
@Expose
var content: String? = null
```

}

```
class Source{
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
var id: String? = null
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
var name: String? = null
```

}

Json from my API(not all)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5GTF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because you have declared **source** in Articles model class as Arraylist. But in actual response, it is coming as an object.

So just modify your Articles class.

Replace these lines

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("source")
var source = ArrayList<Source>()
```

with these ones

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("source")
var source :Source? = null
//or
var source = Source()
```

Comment: Now it issues - Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 59 path

Comment: This is because you have declared some key to return string value. But actually it is returning you an object of values. Can you share your log? And also accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: 2020-10-13 08:49:38.768 4649-4649/com.example.retrofitwork D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

2020-10-13 08:49:39.308 4649-4649/com.example.retrofitwork I/LOL: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 59 path $.articles[0].source

Comment: Can you please check your response? What you are actually getting in source? This error is saying you are getting source as a string. Or you can share your response json with me

Comment: override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<UrlImageModel>, response: Response<UrlImageModel>) {
                val statusResponse = response.body()!!
                            result.text = result.text.toString() + '\n' + statusResponse.articles[1].author + '\n' + statusResponse.articles[1].title]
            }

Comment: or it's not this?

Comment: No, This is not what i am asking for. I am asking for json which you are getting in API response.

Comment: Sorry, i added picture in my question which contains Json from my Api

Comment: I got it. var source :Source? = null should be used. I just corrected the answer. DO check. return type was missed by mistake.

Comment: It will work. If it is still not working do let me know. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

try  changing  Articles Class to this :

```
class Articles{
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("source")
    var source = Source()
    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    var author: String? = null
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    var title: String? = null
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    var description: String? = null
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    var url: String? = null
    @SerializedName("urlToImage")
    @Expose
    var urlToImage: String? = null
    @SerializedName("publishedAt")
    @Expose
    var publishedAt: String? = null
    @SerializedName("content")
    @Expose
    var content: String? = null
```

Comment: I tried this var source? = null because var source = Source() not working and its issues Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 59 path