# Cant get my data from retrofit because "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

So i have this problem where im asking for an array but im getting an object.

im getting some objects like this :

```
{
    "2324": {
        "Install_Date": "2013-11-28",
        "LATITUDE": 0.51664504,
        "LONGITUDE": 0.30964532,
        "Module_Count": 14,
    },
... and some more objects ...
}
```

Where the 2324 is dynamic, so it can change.

How can i get this data from retrofit ?

im using serialized and asking for a list of my Object that i created.

My custom object:

```
data class Asset(
    @SerializedName("Install_Date")
    val assetInstallDate: String,

    @SerializedName("LATITUDE")
    val LATITUDE: Double,

    @SerializedName("LONGITUDE")
    val LONGITUDE: Double,

    @SerializedName("Module_Count")
    val assetModuleCount: Int,
)
```

and my call is:

```
call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Asset>>{
....
}
```

Comment: You can look at the object and use `object.keys()` to get all the keys. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573913/android-jsonobject-how-can-i-loop-through-a-flat-json-object-to-get-each-key-a

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android JSONObject - How can I loop through a flat JSON object to get each key and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573913/android-jsonobject-how-can-i-loop-through-a-flat-json-object-to-get-each-key-a)

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai i know how to do that way, but with retrofit, how can i do that ?

Comment: Change your callback signature to `Callback<JSONObject>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin retrofit expected begin\_array but was begin\_object at line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326723/kotlin-retrofit-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1)

Comment: @JustSightseeing yes, thanks.. Well at least i think it does. Just a curiosity, what does  expose means in retrofit?

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html